# maximum recursion depth exceeded in django

Tags: django-forms

**i have occured error when  i logout then occure this error maximum recursion depth exceeded........................................................................................................... **

```
    template.html
    RecursionError at /logout/
    maximum recursion depth exceeded
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/
    Django Version: 3.0.6
    Exception Type: RecursionError
    Exception Value:    
    maximum recursion depth exceeded
    Exception Location: C:\Users\Aqib\Desktop\Python Djnago\vscode projects\thumbsap\account\views.py in logout, line 213
    Python Executable:  C:\Users\Aqib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.8.3
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\Aqib\\Desktop\\Python Djnago\\vscode projects\\thumbsap',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\Aqib\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
    Server time:    Wed, 3 Jun 2020 04:35:00 +0530
    Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
    C:\Users\Aqib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
   projects\thumbsap\account\views.py in logout
            logout(request) …

views.py


def logout(request):
        logout(request)
        messages.SUCCESS(request,"your successfully logged out")
        return render(request,'home/login.html')
        return HttpResponse("Logged Out Successfully")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the first line of your logout function ...

```
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    .....
```

All this is doing is calling itself with no way of stopping.

I assume that the call to `logout` was intended to call `django.contrib.auth.logout`, and thereofre you have something like this at the top of your module :

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
```

But the problem is when you do

```
def logout(request)
    ....
```

That defines a new `logout` names, and it replaces what you imported.

You have two solutions :

1. rename your `logout(request)`  function, but that will mean changing your url.py, so the new function is invoked
2. Change the import to something else (using an alias) so that `logout` name that is imported isn't overriten

If you opt for option 2, your code will become:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as dca_logout
     ....

def logout(request):
   dca_logout(request)
     ....
```

Using a different name for the `django.contrib.auth.login` will ensure that your logout function doesn't makes the name you import.